# How to prove $\int_0^\pi\biggl |\sum_{i=0}^k \frac{a_i\sin(i+\frac{1}{2})x}{2\sin \frac{1}{2}x}\biggr| \, dx \le c(k+1)$ for some constant $c$?

Tags: calculus, inequality, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

**Let $|a_i|\le1$, prove that $$\int_0^\pi \biggl|\sum_{i=0}^k \frac{a_i\sin(i+\frac{1}{2})x}{2\sin \frac{1}{2}x}\biggr|\,dx \le c(k+1)$$ for some constant $c$.**

I tried to solve the question as follows
$$\int_0^\pi \biggl|\sum_{i=0}^k \frac{a_i\sin(i+\frac{1}{2})x}{2\sin \frac{1}{2}x}\biggr| \, dx \le 
\int_0^\pi \sum_{i=0}^k \biggl| \frac{a_i\sin(i+\frac{1}{2})x}{2\sin \frac{1}{2}x}\biggr|\,dx \\=
\sum_{i=0}^k|a_{i}|\int_0^\pi \biggl| \frac{\sin(i+\frac{1}{2})x}{2\sin \frac{1}{2}x}\biggr|\,dx \le
\sum_{i=0}^k\int_0^\pi \biggl| \frac{\sin(i+\frac{1}{2})x}{2\sin \frac{1}{2}x}\biggr| \, dx.$$
Then it looks like a classic equality about Lebesgue constant,
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \biggl| \frac{\sin(i+\frac{1}{2})x}{2\sin \frac{1}{2}x}\biggr|\,dx=\frac{4}{\pi^2}\log i+O(1).$$
However, it didn't work. The above process of estimation doesn't seem to be careful enough.
How to make more careful and effective estimates to solve the question?
Thank you so much!

Comment: If you divide through by $k+1$, when all $a_i$ are equal you get $a_0$ times the [Fejér kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r_kernel). Since most of the mass of the Dirichlet kernel is near $0$ it's plausible that this situation is more or less the worst case. But proving that looks harder.

Comment: what is wrong with $\sum_{i=1}^k(\log i+O(1)) = O(k) + O(\log k)=O(k)?$

Comment: @dezdichado For any constant $c$, $O(k)\geq c(k+1).$

Comment: If something is O(k), then it's also O(k+1)

Answer (score 1):

On the other forum, I found the answer to this question.The website link is here, https://www.zhihu.com/question/410940277/answer/1400850373.

I copied the proof roughly here.
$$\int_0^\pi \biggl|\sum_{i=0}^k \frac{a_i\sin(i+\frac{1}{2})x}{2\sin \frac{1}{2}x}\biggr| \, dx = \int_0^\frac{\pi}{k+1} \biggl|\sum_{i=0}^k \frac{a_i\sin(i+\frac{1}{2})x}{2\sin \frac{1}{2}x}\biggr| \, dx+\int_\frac{\pi}{k+1}^\pi \biggl|\sum_{i=0}^k \frac{a_i\sin(i+\frac{1}{2})x}{2\sin \frac{1}{2}x}\biggr| \, dx$$
It is easy to get that $$\frac{\sin(i+\frac{1}{2})x}{2\sin \frac{1}{2}x} \le i+\frac12.$$
Then $$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{k+1} \biggl|\sum_{i=0}^k \frac{a_i\sin(i+\frac{1}{2})x}{2\sin \frac{1}{2}x}\biggr| \, dx \le \frac{\pi}{k+1}\sum_{i=0}^{k}|a_i|\biggl(i+\frac12\biggr) \le \frac\pi2(k+1).$$
According to **Cauchy-Schwarz** inequality,we have
$$\int_\frac{\pi}{k+1}^\pi \biggl|\sum_{i=0}^k \frac{a_i\sin(i+\frac{1}{2})x}{2\sin \frac{1}{2}x}\biggr| \, dx \le \sqrt{\int_\frac{\pi}{k+1}^\pi \biggl(\frac{1}{2\sin \frac{1}{2}x}\biggr)^2 \, dx}\sqrt{\int_\frac{\pi}{k+1}^\pi \biggl(\sum_{i=0}^k a_i\sin(i+\frac{1}{2})x\biggr)^2 \, dx}.$$
After calculation,we get that $$\int_\frac{\pi}{k+1}^\pi \biggl(\frac{1}{2\sin \frac{1}{2}x}\biggr)^2 \, dx \lt 2k+2,$$
and $$\int_\frac{\pi}{k+1}^\pi \biggl(\sum_{i=0}^k a_i\sin(i+\frac{1}{2})x\biggr)^2 \, dx \le \int_{-\pi}^\pi \biggl(\sum_{i=0}^k a_i\sin(i+\frac{1}{2})x\biggr)^2 \, dx=\pi\sum_{i=0}^{k}a_i^2 \le \pi(k+1).$$
Therefore, $$\int_\frac{\pi}{k+1}^\pi \biggl|\sum_{i=0}^k \frac{a_i\sin(i+\frac{1}{2})x}{2\sin \frac{1}{2}x}\biggr| \, dx \le \sqrt{2\pi}(k+1).$$
In brief, we come to the conclusion $$\int_0^\pi \biggl|\sum_{i=0}^k \frac{a_i\sin(i+\frac{1}{2})x}{2\sin \frac{1}{2}x}\biggr| \, dx \le (\frac\pi2+\sqrt{2\pi})(k+1).$$